# Blackberry Q10 and Z10 Media Queries

Tags: css, media-queries, blackberry-10

Is there any way to focus on those two screens with media queries.

Here's my code for the Q10 but it doesn't work:

```
@media all and (max-height: 720px) and (max-width: 720px) and (min-resolution: 330dpi) {}
```

Any thought?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For the Q10, I would use this: `@media screen and(device-height:720px)and(device-width:720px)`

Comment: I think I figured it out.  @media screen and (max-width: 720px) and (max-height: 720px) (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)

Answer (score 1):

I used to select bb q10 in this way:

```
@media screen and (device-height: 347px) and (device-width: 347px)
              and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:2.075)
{
}
```

Don't ask me why such weird values, works for me with BBOS 10.2.1.3062

Answer (score 1):

Blackberry Q10  has a peculiar display.  If you can't get it to look good in the range of your other media queries, try setting your specifications for Q10 at the end of your stylesheet, like:

```
@media screen and (device-width: 347px){
}
```